# Jira query to return issue status in a specific date using resolution date

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jql, jira-rest-java-api

I am trying to run a query using a resolution date and retrieve a list of results with the actual status according to the resolution date.

When running this query today, I receive a list with the resolved bugs while I would like to know if they were open during this period of time.

In my case, I would like to request the query using a rest API and if the bug was "open" on the 01-01-2017, I'd like to get it in the response even though it is closed now.

Thanks!

**Update:**
Resolution date displays the current status of an issue between dates but not the status according to the dates mentioned in the query itself.

```
resolutiondate > "2017/01/01" and resolutiondate < "2017/02/01"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible in JQL to search by a specific status on a given date, for example, it is not possible to find issues that were in status "IN PROGRESS" between 2017-01-01 and 2017-02-01. However, it is possible to find issues that were resolved between two dates like:

```
resolutiondate > "2017/01/01" and resolutiondate < "2017/02/01"
```

or closer to your case, find issues that until 2017-01-01 remained unresolved (that were resolved after 2017-01-01 to be precise):

```
resolutiondate > "2017/01/01"
```

and you can extend this to:

```
resolutiondate > "2017/01/01" or resolutiondate is EMPTY
```

and this will find all issues that were unresolved until 2017-01-01 or are still unresolved. Keep in mind that this will not work 100% reliable when an issue was reopened, for example, the issue could be resolved before 2017-01-01, then reopened and resolved later, it will appear in the query results (not sure if this is what you want).

Comment: Thanks, I know about resolution date query option but I actually need the specific status on a given date.

Answer (score 1):

Try
`status was "Open" ON "2017-01-01"`